# MVC Razor display-label

Tags: css, razor

If I have the following Razor, it shows Counter in bold. How do I get it to show it not bold?

```
    <div class="display-label">Counter:</div>
```

Comment: Did you check you rules in the CSS file for "display-label" class?

Comment: Check the stylesheet for the "display-label" class and remove any css that would cause the text to be boldface. Without more of the HTML I can't tell if you missed closing a tag or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your display-label css class, you can override the style inline, like so:

```
<div class="display-label" style="font-weight: normal">Counter:</div>
```

It's probably better to change it in the css file though, if you want all your display labels to not be bold.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://forums.asp.net/t/1900287.aspx?Where+are+the+CSS+classes+generated+in+the+views+by+the+MVC+4+project+template+in+VS+2012+ Those CSS classes are only placeholders in MVC 4 Razor.  I know for a fact that they don't exist in the autogenerated Site.css file.  To use these classes to characterize those divs you would need to create classes with those names and those criteria.  The boldness of the labels generated by the labelfor and label html helpers are derived from "label" style in the Site.css which by default is {display : block; font-size: 1.2 em; font-weight : 600;}  Change this style to change the rendering of the html.label and html.labelfor helpers